# Using yarn-client from java Spark

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying Spark in Java. I have created a Maven project in Eclipse with the following typical example:

```
package maver4spark.exampleSpark;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "/folder/file.txt";     
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount").setMaster("yarn-client"); 
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);   
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("a"); }
    }).count();

    long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
      public Boolean call(String s) { return s.contains("b"); }
    }).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
  }
}
```

When running this application in Eclipse I get the error

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Unable to load YARN support
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$.liftedTree1$1(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:399)
```

if I replace the `setmaster` by `setMaster("local[2]");` it works fine.
The pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I have also installed hadoop and spark.  Hadoop (single node) and yarn daemons are running, and spark works fine from the shell. The problem is that I don't know how to connect the Java application with the Hadoop file system. I would prefer to try the application in Eclipse and not use spark-submit.